# PDF file inside a SOAP message (not as attachement)

Tags: web-services, pdf, soap

Do you know a tool that converts a PDF in base64 format so i can sent it via a SOAP message ?
I use SOAP UI.

Comment: I am not here to get points ,rather to find answers and help.But i do not see the reason to vote down for this ...just because you are able to do that.I am sure other will benefit out of this.google for the anser and you'll see is not easy to find answer to this question concretly.

Comment: @Chris, the downvote might be because you are saying "...converts a PDF in binary format" when PDF is actually a binary file. On top of that you put as answer that you use some website to convert your file into base64encode, which is a text format. And finally, using some website to convert your file is not a programming related answer, and there are many ways of converting a file into a base64string in almost every programming language.

Comment: agree with you and i did the changes.

Comment: i needed a tool since i mentioned i am using soap ui where i have to paste the text message inside the soap request.Programatically the problem was solved in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this helpful tools which solved my problem:
http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/
http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/

So i upload the pdf file and as a result i get the base64 format which i copy inside the soap message.

You need to paste the result of encoded pdf file inside the necessary tags and that's it.
Mention:without any CDATA

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on this?  I am looking at doing something similar.